# Streaming 3D numpy arrays into tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have found the flow_from_directory function of ImageDataGenerator and I have a function for importing the files I want but I can't figure out how to correctly merge the two together.

Currently I have some generators:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=input_shape[:3],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='binary')

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=input_shape[:3],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='binary')
```

and then I have the function for import

```
def OpenMrc(filename):
    # filename must be string
    map = mrcfile.read(filename)
    return map
```

essentially I want the generators to call the OpenMrc function when they are trawling the directories to stream in the files but for the life of me I can't find the way to do that. I may just be missing something obvious?

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: I would recommend against using ImageDataGenerator, which is deprecated. You can build your own pipeline with the [`tf.data` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) instead. You will probably need to wrap your reading function in a `tf.numpy_function`-